# PHP For Loop Checking Folder for existing Files

Tags: php, apache

This is the only code messing up the php, I removed it and it resumes perfecty, so I am guessing something within this loop statement is wrong; can someone please see whats wrong?

The below suppose to search the folder and see if the image is already within that folder, if so it chnges the $i by +1 each time ($i++) and then checks again with a max of 30 number.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?
Error I Get:

```
"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while     the server was attempting to fulfill the request"
```

So must be something within the code not configured correctly

-Php Loop Code

```
<?php

define ("MAX_SIZE","100"); 


 function getExtension($str) {
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; }
     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
 }


 $errors=0;
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 {

$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];

if ($image) 
{

    $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") &&     ($extension != "gif")) 
    {

//print error message

echo "";

        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {

$size=filesize(['image']['tmp_name']);

if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
echo "";

$errors=1;
}

 $image_name=time().'.'.$extension;



//Error Occurs Below
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++)
{
$relativePath="members/image/corey/"."photo".$i;
if(!file_exists($relativePath)) {
    continue;
}
    else
{
    $newNumber=$i;
    break;
}
}
$fileName=$_FILES["name"]."$newNumber";
$relativePath="members/image/corey/".$filename.'.'.$extension;
move_uploaded_file($image, $relativePath);

//Error Occurs Above
?>
```

-Buttons

```
    <form name="newad" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="">
  <table>
  <tr><td><table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input name="Submit" id="upload" type="submit" value="Upload image" onclick"load_images()" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td></tr>
  </table>      
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your error log. Learn how to use error reporting and logging. Then give a line-number where the actual error occurs and rephrase your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: The error within php and when I do the error log within actual Browser php doesn't show

Comment: also my error log in dreamweaver doesnt show anything; but the page still doesn't work

Comment: You need to (configure and) look into the PHP error log: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) is not a PHP error message, it's Apache... @hakre - he can't provide line number with this error (or at least not in an easy way)

Comment: Php is configured correctly, i have other php files that work with no problem, its just the for loop which screws everything up i can remove it and it works fine

Comment: What other way could I provide it?

Comment: so the `for()` block runs once but causes an error if runs twice and more??

Comment: no when I remove the 'for()' block it runs but when I keep it there it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 (Internal Server Error) can be given for various reasons, one of them is that PHP exited with a fatal error. You find the PHP errors in your PHP error log if you configure it.

If you have configured the PHP error log and you don't find anything related to the script in there, you need to check the server's error log. It logs all 500 errors and gives you the reason.

You can even check the servers error log first, however the reason in there might seem very cryptic and only tells you (if you know how to read it) that it was a PHP error - which is better explained in the php error log.

If you don't have access to your servers error log files, contact the technical support of your hoster.

Comment: You can't get a 500 server error w/o having this logged in the server's error log (or if that *really* would be the case, your hosting is terribly screwed).

Comment: It none of this data 3/8/2012 showing they all are from 2 months+ ago

Comment: wait.. I think my apache system time is off since it says '2010' and I only had apache up for 5 months

Comment: Contact your hoster where you find the *actual* error log - not the archives.

Comment: It local host at the moment. I'm in process of dev. the website myself and then hosting locally until finished. It's not public

Comment: Okay, then you're hosting on your own, so the technical support is you. Look into the product documentation of your webserver where the error log is located.

Comment: What would be the best bet to fix the server configuration? cause all my other php works and just when I add the for loop statement it screw this one up. I guess trial and error my best bet. Thanks all

Comment: That sounds (but must not be) like a a) syntax error / b) endless loop / c) memory limit. But you need to do proper error configuration first otherwise you will always look into the dark.

Comment: that's beyond me, maybe @hakre might be able to help you better, I am not really a server admin... however, PHP should display errors, if it doesn't = misconfig... if it's a permissions or server related issue = misconfig... in my opinion

Comment: memory limit can't be the problem. so i guess endless loop

Comment: Stop guessing, start reading logs. if no logs, configure logs. that simple it is. You should not need to think much when doing debugging. And stop to guess if it takes longer than 3 minutes to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

500 (Internal Server Error) in my opinion is an error due to misconfiguration of the server, i.e. invalid .htaccess directives, maybe permission problems. You should make sure that you have the permissions to write to the directories you wish to and to access them etc. and that there are no .htaccess files with invalid directives in this directories...

Comment: but when i take the parts i put within // away it all works fine then. just when i had the for loop statement it screws up.

Comment: yes, cause either `move_uploaded_file($image, $relativePath);` causes the error... or @hakre is right, basically only these two option exist... but as @hakre says - you have to look in apache for the error...